# Is this triple integral between cylinder and a plane independent of $\pi$?

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry, volume, multiple-integral

Picture of full problem where Dan's share is part of interest:

[image: Picture of full problem where Dan's share is part of interest]

The image shows the full problem. The issue is raised when calculating Dan's share of the drink.

(1) Equation of plane in Dan's share must pass through $(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)\space and\space (0,R,h)$. Therefore the CARTESIAN equation of the plane is:
$$ 
z=\frac{hy}{R}$$ and the cylindrical equation is:
$$z=\frac{h}{R}r\sin\theta$$

(2) The jacobian in cyldindrical coordinates is $r$, therfoe the volume element is: $$dA=r dr  d\theta dz$$

(3) The limits of Dan's portion in cylindrical coordinates are:
$$z: 0 \rightarrow \frac{h}{R}r\sin\theta \hspace{0.5cm}\vert\hspace{0.5cm} \theta: 0\rightarrow \pi \hspace{0.5cm}\vert\hspace{0.5cm}  r:0\rightarrow R  $$

(4)The triple integral for Dan's share is therefore:

$$\LARGE \int_{0}^{R}\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{hr\sin\theta}{R}}r\,\, dz d\theta dr$$

(5) Evaluating:
$$\large \int_{0}^{R}\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{h\sin\theta}{R}r^{2}\,\, d\theta dr$$

$$\large \int_{0}^{R}\left[\frac{-h}{R}r^{2}\cos\theta\right]_{0}^{\pi}\,\, dr$$
$$\large \int_{0}^{R}\frac{2h}{R}r^{2}\,\, dr$$

(6) Final answer is therefore :
$$\LARGE \frac{2}{3}hR^{2}$$

This seems very odd to me as a semicircular based shaped has a volume that is independent of $\pi$. Is this true or have I made a mistake?

A related question is why does this shape not count as a pyramid? It has a shape that goes  to a point. I thought that was the condition for a pyramid. But that would mean the area should be $\frac{1}{6}\pi R^{2}$.

Comment: pyramid has straight edges and you seem to be cutting by a circle or a parabola of some sort

Comment: @gt6989b this sort of parabola has the name "ellipse". :)

Comment: @user i could not tell from the picture what the curve was and there was no description :)

Comment: @gt6989b any cross-section of cylinder by a plane is an ellipse (sometimes it degenerates to a circle or to a pair of parallel lines).  :)

Comment: Computation of the volume in a different  way gives rise to the same result.

Comment: @user thanks for insight, didn't occur to me :) If you write up your solution as an answer, I'd be happy to upvote it

Comment: I have asked this question previously here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2436656/what-happend-to-pi . This result was known to Archimedes.

Answer (score 1):

Let us calculate the volume of the body in a more straightforward (but by no means a better) way:

Consider horizontal slices of the body. They are [circular segments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment) with the area ($\phi$ is one half of $\theta$ from the wikipedia page):
$$
A_\phi =R^2\left(\phi-\sin\phi\cos\phi\right),
$$ 
with $\cos\phi=y/R=z/h$.

Therefore:
$$
V=\int_0^h A_{\phi(z)}dz=R^2h\int_0^{\pi/2} \left(\phi-\sin\phi\cos\phi\right)\sin\phi\, d\phi\\=R^2h\left[\sin\phi-\phi\cos\phi-\frac{1}{3}\sin^3\phi\right]_0^{\pi/2}=\frac{2}{3}R^2h.
$$
This confirms the correctness of the result.